# Excel Power Query Improper Json Grouping

Tags: json, excel, powerquery

I'm trying to parse a json file but the file is set up in a strange way that excel is having problems deciphering. Please see code example below.

```
"provider_references":
[
{"provider_group_id":380.60,"provider_groups":[{"npi":[1234597899,3214569878],"tin":{"type":"ein","value":"57-xxxxxxx"}}]}, {"provider_group_id":380.6,"provider_groups":[{"npi":[1591591599,3333333333],"tin":{"type":"ein","value":"57-xxxxxxx"}}]}
]
```

There is a field called Group_ID, that power query is reading as a number data type. This field has some rows with the entry 380.6 and some rows with an entry of 380.60.  Excel is reading both 380.6 and 380.60 lines as 380.6. . I tried to change the data type in Power Query Editor to text, thinking this would solve the problem, but excel is still not able to differentiate between the two entries and continues to lump the 380.6 and 380.60 Group_IDs together.  Is there a way to ensure that any slight differences in the group_ID field gets captured when parsing the json file?

```
This is how the json file should be parsed

|Provider_Group_ID |NPI         |Type       |
|:-----------------|:----------:|----------:|
|  380.60          |1234597899  |57-xxxxxxx | 
|  380.60          |3214569879  |57-xxxxxxx |
|  380.6           |1591591599  |57-xxxxxxx |
|  380.6           |3333333333  |57-xxxxxxx |

But this is how power query is actually parsing the file

|Provider_Group_ID |NPI         |Type       |
|:-----------------|:----------:|----------:|
|  380.6           |1234597899  |57-xxxxxxx | 
|  380.6           |3214569879  |57-xxxxxxx |
|  380.6           |1591591599  |57-xxxxxxx |
|  380.6           |3333333333  |57-xxxxxxx |
```

Answer (score 1):

In powerquery, try pre-processing the JSON to convert the numbers to text.

JSON:

```
{
"provider_references":
[
{"provider_group_id":380.60,"provider_groups":[{"npi":[1234597899,3214569878],"tin":{"type":"ein","value":"57-xxxxxxx"}}]}, {"provider_group_id":380.6,"provider_groups":[{"npi":[1591591599,3333333333],"tin":{"type":"ein","value":"57-xxxxxxx"}}]}
]}
```

Powerquery code using **provider_group_id":** and **,"provider_groups** as the markers for the desired spot to add quotes

```
let  Source = Table.FromColumns({Lines.FromBinary(File.Contents("C:\temp\a.json"), null, null, 1252)}),
#"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(Source,"provider_group_id"":","provider_group_id"":""",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Column1"}),
#"Replaced Value1" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value",",""provider_groups""",""",""provider_groups""",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Column1"}),
NewJson=Json.Document(Text.Combine( #"Replaced Value1"[Column1],""))
in NewJson
```

[image]

alternate:

```
let  Source = Lines.FromBinary(File.Contents("C:\temp\a.json"), null, null, 1252),
#"Replaced Value" = List.Transform(Source, each Text.Replace(Text.From(_),"provider_group_id"":","provider_group_id"":""")),
#"Replaced Value2"=List.Transform(#"Replaced Value", each Text.Replace(Text.From(_),",""provider_groups""",""",""provider_groups""")),
NewJson=Json.Document(Text.Combine( #"Replaced Value2",""))
in NewJson
```

Comment: There is another file that I have to do the same thing but because the 380 number is in a different part of the json file the code given above doesnt work.

Comment: the above should work on anything surrounded by the provider_group_id": and ,"provider_groups"  bookends. What is your new JSON look like? Edit your question or start a new one  We can only answer the question based on the sample data you share

Comment: If this solved your question please mark as accepted